# ajax requests -- application.js versus application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Would like to put any js functions in application.js or other .js file.

However, doing ajax experiments I'm finding only the javascript functions are only working if placed in application.html.erb.

If I put them in application.js I end up with non-helpful browser errors.

Have experimented with both link_to and XMLHttpRequest directly

Any thoughts? Shouldn't application.js be generally visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. application.js is only visible if you explicitly include in your HEAD section as:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application.js' %>
```

If you do:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

it also looks for application.js.

The code below is what I'm using to include jQuery, jQuery-UI and my own application.js

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application.js" %>
```

Comment: Thank you Steve! Yes, I think I followed some instructions when adding jquery so replaced the 'defaults' include...?

Comment: I added a bit of code in the answer above that should include what you need.